# Can Blender's keymaps be used for key (chaining / chords)?

Tags: shortcut

Some applications support [key-chaining](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings#Key_chains), also known as [shortcut-chords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248624/visual-studio-2010-keyboard-shortcut-chords) (MSVC and EMacs for example).

This is where an initial shortcut waits for other keys to be pressed to complete the key-chain or chord.

While Blender's key-map editor doesn't support this directly, is it possible to setup key-chaining in Blender?